# How to open UNC path containg spaces in run dialog box

Tags: windows-7, windows, unc, run-dialog

I've got a network location which contains several folders with spaces in them and want to be able to start a program by using Run and the program's UNC path. For example: open the run dialog box, put in \\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\program.exe and program.exe starts. I'm fairly certain that the problem is related to the spaces in the name because I can confirm that it is neither a connectivity issue, nor a permissions one.

I have tried:

"\\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\program.exe"

'\\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\program.exe'

\\itserver\files\"IT Programs"\"Example Program"\program.exe

"\\itserver\files\'IT Programs'\'Example Program'\program.exe"

<\\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\program.exe>

\\itserver\files\IT%20Programs\Example%20Program\program.exe

Also, renaming the folders is not an option.

EDIT:
I fixed the error in which only one of the slashes showed originally in the file path by adding a third slash as well as clarified what I tried

Comment: and you have confirmed that if you browse to the executable you can run it with a double click, and that "\\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\" opens the folder containing the exe?

Comment: I can access it and run it by going both through a network drive or typing in \\itserver\files and browsing from there

Comment: but "\\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\" (with the double quotes) in the run bar does not work?

Comment: Nope, that gives me a "Windows cannot access..." network error

Comment: all I can say is doublecheck your spelling. the spaces are not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution is to use double quotes like so:

```
"\\itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\program.exe"
```

This should work for windows bases systems going back from XP to 8.1 (and possibly older - I don't have kit to test on)

Also, please note that you need a double slash before a server name:

\\server\share\folder\subfolder\file.exe

**"\\"** indicates a server

**"\"** indicates an object on the server (share, folder, file etc)

Comment: I fixed the original post so that it shows the second slash, I'm sure it was a formatting issue. I do know that \\ indicates a server. Also, I have clarified the question to show that I already tried the solution you suggested, but it doesn't work, hence the confusion.

Comment: @MattSteelblade, it should work, this answer is correct, albeit not helpful to your specific issue. I've just run several different executables on another server using double quotes around the whole exe path in the run bar.

Comment: I've marked this the answer because it should have worked initially

Answer (score 2):

Using:

file:////itserver\files\IT Programs\Example Program\program.exe

it worked! I have no idea what's going on, or why when using double quotes it produced an error message...

Answer (score -1):

To run a file from a network share, you need to put a double slash before the server name or IP, not a single slash.

After you have done that, put quotes around the path.

Example:

> "\\server\share\folder name\MyApp.exe"

instead of

> "\server\share\folder name\MyApp.exe"

Comment: Fixed the formatting issue on superuser to show the path.